# How to setup CI/CD for api/angular app/db project to AZURE app services?

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a VSTS local GIT REPO with a solution file that has these 3 projects (and some test projects):
1. API
2. Angular App
3. SQL Server DB Project.

I am trying to setup CI/CD for this setup to my azure app services account with 3 deployment slots: dev/qa/stage. What is the best way to configure these settings? I am having hard time setting up CD in Azure Platform not knowing how to link deployments of 3 different types of project.

Comment: This is too broad; creating the release definitions and setting up the pipeline are very independent tasks (and I'm not sure which you are asking about). Please try to be more specific with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a generic question but here is some tips but you need to get something up and running before you have specific questions.

I would if possible split the angular APP and the API (Assuming this is Web API) into separate Repos if possible. It makes it easier. VSTS has some CI built in but i've used bitbucket and Azure built in CI with slots. Make sure you using a cloud version of VSTS or use bitbucket.

To do it in Azure once you have split the repos build a web application for the Angular app go deployment options and setup VSTS and the repo and branch you want it to deploy from. Once done it will automatically build the server for you. With regards to the scaling settings for the angular box it can be in a resource group which has low CPU etc as its a client side app.

For the API again build a web application connect it (Deployment options) to the repository and branch you want and it will automatically build it. Depending on the complexity make sure this app has the correct amount of CPU etc.

Remember to use application settings to add any settings you want to override from the web.config.

For slots on both of these press add slot, you get option to copy configuration from the main app. Normally I would say have two slots per application or it get to confusing when swapping them. Also certain service plans don't allow slots.

So I would have a **Develop** branch in git that builds dev web application with no slots. And have a **release** or **master** branch of a repository that builds the staging slot of a web application which can be spun with the release version. Also you don't want to connect the live slot up to source control, when you swap the previous production slot becomes wired to the repository.

Hope that helps good luck

Alex